# Where is the Superset Helm Chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I am looking for a helm chart of [Superset](https://superset.apache.org/) to set it up on Kubernetes which is hosted remotely. In other words I would like to call "helm repo add" on a remote url.

I found this one [here](https://github.com/helm/charts#%EF%B8%8F-deprecation-and-archive-notice) but it says that it is deprecated with no reference to a new location. The only thing I could find is this pull request, but the [repository](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/24466/files) it is leading to does not seem to contain Superset.
Does anyone know if there is still a remote Superset helm chart somewhere out there?

Comment: Did [the one in their repo](https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/0.38.1/helm/superset) not work for you?

Comment: I was hoping for a remotely hosted helm chart so that I can easily update it and make it available for different programmers without the need to download the Github project each time. In other words, I would like to call "helm repo add" on a remote url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes)

A helm chart has been published and can be added as

```
helm repo add superset https://apache.github.io/superset
```

Then installed

```
helm upgrade --install --values my-values.yaml superset superset/superset
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/helm/superset
is where I found the code of the chart